# Swift On Demand Resources Queueing Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm having what I think is a queueing issue. I've never really understood queueing, so really appreciate any help.

```
var ODRtags: Set = ["Soprano", "Alto", "Tenor", "Bass", "KeyCentre"]
...
    func testForChangeRangeMessage() {
        let test = ODRtags.checkIfTagsAvailable()
        if test == false {
                showExerciseDownloadAlert = true
        }
        print ("tests show content downloaded = \(test)")
    }
...
extension Set where Element == String {
    func checkIfTagsAvailable()-> Bool {
        let currentRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: self)
        var avail = false
        currentRequest.conditionallyBeginAccessingResources { status in
            avail = status
            print ("Donwloaded?? \(status)")
        }
        return avail
    }
}
```

So, ideally what would happen is the first func checks if the ODRs are downloaded, using the extension. If not, it'll make a message pop up asking to download them. The issue is that the
`print ("tests show content downloaded = \(test)")` prints 'false' first, then the `print ("Donwloaded?? \(status)")` prints true. So it would seem that the first function is calling the extension function, but then continuing on without waiting for an answer from it. I don't really understand Queueing, but I tried throwing both functions inside `DispatchQueue.main.async {`, with no change in result.

Comment: How is `conditionallyBeginAccessingResources` implemented? Does it run its completion on another thread? It looks like `currentRequest.conditionallyBeginAccessingResources` is an asynchronous call, the result of which is not waited before returning from `checkIfTagsAvailable()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! This is how I ended up solving it.

```
var ODRtags: Set = ["Soprano", "Alto", "Tenor", "Bass", "KeyCentre"]
...
    func testForChangeRangeMessage() {
        globalVars.ODRtags.checkIfTagsAvailable(onSucsess: onSucsess, onFailure: onFailure)
    }
    func onSucsess() {
        print ("Content already downloaded")
    }
    func onFailure() {
        print ("Content not downloaded. Prompting now")
        showExerciseDownloadAlert = true
    }
...
extension Set where Element == String {
    func checkIfTagsAvailable(onSucsess: @escaping () -> Void, onFailure: @escaping () -> Void){
        
        let currentRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: self)
        
        currentRequest.conditionallyBeginAccessingResources { status in
            if status == true {
                onSucsess()
                return
            }
            onFailure()
        }
    }
}
```